# OpenCv crashes when calling from android activity

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

i have this code in which i use openCV to launch a camera. The code is given below. If this class "MainActivity" is used as the main class then every thing works fine but if i use it from another activity then the application crashes.

Here's the code of openCV android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {

private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
               // Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this,     mLoaderCallback);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
     setContentView(R.layout.helloopencvlayout);
     mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.HelloOpenCvView);
     mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
     mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener((CvCameraViewListener2) this);

}

@Override
 public void onPause()
 {
     super.onPause();
     if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
         mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
 }

 public void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
         mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
 }

 public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
 }

 public void onCameraViewStopped() {
 }

 public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
     return inputFrame.rgba();

 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Now if i try to call this from another activity using intent in which i just have a button and onclick method is implemented and when the button is pressed , this activity is called , the application crashes.

It's been more the 4 hours , i am struggling with it. Please help and thanks in advance.

What i believe is that there is a callback method implemented , so we can't call this activity as normal activity call , or may be some other concept. I search it on the internet , but nothing helps. Some where i also found the concept of Async call , but i didn't get it.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: The problem is solved by struggling for more then one day. It was the problem on oncreate function . Instead if typecasting this , if i type cast MainActivity.this , the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will use try catch block on the oncreate function then you will come to know that the problem is of typecasting exception that is application can't typecast the org.opencv activity class to your activity.

So Instead if typecasting this , if i type cast MainActivity.this , the problem is solved.

Simple but took me hell of time to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

By using AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html you can make all the job you made in onCreate method of your activity. You can use "onProgressUpdate" method for getting frames in "Mat" format.

You don't have to use intent and another activity for this job. If you check AsyncTask documentation, you will see it is not so complex.

Comment: thanks for the info , but the problem is solved. It was the problem of typecasting means using MainActivity.this , instead of just this in on create function.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that there are two thread running, please check out the thread issues like Sync and Async.

Another point that worth your attention is how OpenCV4Android utility is calling the MainActivity Class. As you can see the class extends CameraViewListener, so it is intended to be called by some other mechanism. So make it clear by refering to the manual of OpenCV4Android.

Also, please check out the layout. Make sure there is a "cameraView" in the layout.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions bro , but the problem is solved. It was the problem of typecasting means using MainActivity.this , instead of just this in on create function.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback to the problem and notifying me.